# CPU time out error

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, cpulimit

Getting CPU time out error for below code:

```
Public class ResponseTimeCal
{
    Public boolean isFirst= True;
    Public DateTime BalVar;
    Public long BalHours;
    Public Long seconds,minutes,hours,milliseconds;
    Public void ResponseTimeCalMeth()
    {
        list<opportunity> l1 =[select Response_Date__c,createdDate,ownerID,Response_check__c  from opportunity where id in:Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        for(opportunity oppObj:l1)
        {//opportunity oldOpp = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);
            If((oppObj.ownerID!='005n0000002KN6V')&&(oppObj.ownerID!=NULL)&&(oppObj.Response_check__c==False))
            {
                oppObj.Response_Date__c = system.now();
                oppObj.Response_check__c=True;
                system.debug('@@@Response date is' + oppObj.Response_Date__c );
                ResponseTimeCal(oppObj.createdDate,oppObj.Response_Date__c);          
            }
        }
    }

    Public void ResponseTimeCal(Datetime startDate, Datetime endDate)
    {
        system.debug('@@@method called');
        while(Date.valueOf(startDate)<=Date.valueOf(endDate))
        {
            if((isFirst==True)&&((startDate.format('EEE')!='Sat')||(startDate.format('EEE')!='Sun')))
            {
                milliseconds = startDate.getTime();
                BalVar = startDate;
                seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
                minutes = seconds / 60;
                hours = minutes / 60;
                BalHours = hours - 17;
                BalVar = BalVar.addDays(1);
                startDate=startDate.addDays(1);
                //valueof(oppObj.createdDate.format(‘MMMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm:ss a’));
                system.debug('Value of BalVar'+ BalHours);
                isFirst=false;
                //return(BalHours); 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, surinder! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and scroll through the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the mechanics. When an answer solves the problem at hand, community etiquette is to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) to indicate to the community you no longer need help with this problem. Of course you are under no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 5):

You have a `while` loop that may never exit, because there are iterations where you do not increment `startDate`. If you never enter your `if` condition, you never increment `startDate`, and you will basically have `while(true)` with no `break` until you completely consume your CPU Limit. Move this line outside the conditional:

```
startDate = startDate.addDays(1);
```